# using find() in matlab

Tags: matlab, function, matrix

Say I have a matrix `A` of dimension `Nx3` where `N` is the number of rows. `A` stores coordinates x,y,z. Now say I already have a set of known coordinates B = [x' y' z'] which I wanna look up in `A`. I wanna find out the number of which row index in `A` stores (x',y',z'). How can I do this? I am guessing I will have to use `find()`

Answer (score 5):

you can use `find`, for example

```
find(A(:,1)==B(1) & A(:,2)==B(2) & A(:,3)==B(3))
```

will yield the index of the  row\rows that match.

Try to get use to reading the documentation of Matlab, it is all there...

by the way, an alternative is to use `ismember`:

```
[~,id]=ismember(B,A,'rows')
```

the variable `id` will yield  the index of the rows where `B` matched `A`.

Comment: `ismember` is the better option here.